# How to do multiple request POST in django?

Tags: django

I have a view that sends a form to another view so that the user can review his form, and then after making another request post to save at that moment... so when the user enters the review view, he enters in request.POST and the form ends up being saved at the wrong time

```
def resumo(request, avaliado_id):
    print(request.method == 'POST')
    perfil = Perfil.objects.filter(user_id=avaliado_id)
    queryDict = request.POST
    notas = (list(queryDict.values()))
    criterios = (list(queryDict.keys())) 
    valores = (list(queryDict.values()))
    valores =  [float(x.replace(",",".")) for x in valores[2:]]
    
    pesos = (queryDict.getlist('pesos'))
    pesos = [float(x.replace(",",".")) for x in pesos]

    res_list = [valores[i] * pesos[i] for i in range(len(valores))]
    media = sum(res_list)
    lista = zip(criterios[2:], notas[2:])
    print(list(lista))
    
    query_criterio = Criterio.objects.filter(ativo = True).values_list('id', flat=True)
    lista_criterio_id = list(query_criterio)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        avaliado = Perfil.objects.get(pk = avaliado_id)
        avaliador = request.user.perfil
        avaliacao = Avaliacao.objects.create(avaliador = avaliador, avaliado= avaliado, media = media)
        avaliacao.save()
        print(avaliacao.id)
        for nota, criterio in zip(notas[2:], lista_criterio_id):
            nota = Notas.objects.create(avaliacao = Avaliacao.objects.get(pk = avaliacao.id), notas = nota, criterios = Criterio.objects.get( pk = criterio))
            nota.save()
        


    context = {
        'media' : media,
        'chaves_e_valores' : zip(criterios[2:], notas[2:]),
        'perfis' : perfil,
    } 
    return render(request, 'admin/resumo.html', context)
```

in the first line "request.method == 'POST'" returns True and because of that it ends up hitting in conditional if.

Comment: maybe i can try to do request.is_ajax() to differentiate the two requests but not returns JSON, just returns True to request.is_ajax()... how can i do that?

Comment: You could pass a step/status/action parameter to the view as you pass avavaliado_id and react on it or use a seperate view only for the review

Comment: Or use a hidden form field to indicate if in review or save step